# Oracle 12c Installation on windows - Installer validation Failed

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, privileges, failed-installation

I been working on installing Oracle 12c database on my windows machine. I downloaded the Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit 2.8GB) file [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html).

Then I extracted the zip file into a folder in my Desktop and run the setup.exe

But I keep on getting this error and am unable to move forth.

> [INS-30131] Initial setup required for the execution of installer validations failed.
> _______________________________________________________________
> **Cause -** Failed to access the temporary location. 
>  **Action -** Ensure that the current user has required permissions to access the temporary location.
>   **Additional Information:**
>    - PRVG-1901 : failed to setup CVU remote execution framework directory "C:\Users\Taro\AppData\Local\Temp\CVU_12.2.0.1.0_Taro\" on nodes "nayantara-jeyaraj"  
> - Cause:  An operation requiring remote execution could not complete because
>            the attempt to set up the Cluster Verification Utility remote
>            execution framework failed on the indicated nodes at the
>            indicated directory location because the CVU remote execution
>            framework version did not match the CVU java verification
>            framework version. The accompanying message provides detailed
>            failure information.
>   - Action:  Ensure that the directory indicated exists or can be created and
>            the user executing the checks has sufficient permission to
>            overwrite the contents of this directory. Also review the
>            accompanying error messages and respond to them. Summary of the failed nodes nayantara-jeyaraj  - Version of exectask could not be retrieved from node "nayantara-jeyaraj"  - Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available  - Action: User Action Not Available  - Version of exectask could not be retrieved from node "nayantara-jeyaraj"  - Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available  - Action: User Action Not Available

According to the error, I checked the *C:\Users\Taro\AppData\Local\Temp* folder permissions under its properties panel's security tab. All the users have full access permissions.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for the DBA site.  It may help to add some more details, such as your version of Windows, and which features you selected (RAC?, CDB?, which of the 4 authentication options did you choose?, etc.)

Comment: I got a link with commands for Linux:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66234/ins-30131initial-setup-required-for-the-execution-of-installer-validations-fai

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This helped me:

```
setup.exe -ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.db.validate.supportedOSCheck=false"
```

I also

- run the console as administrator
- checked whether a `REG DWORD` named `AutoShareWks` (in registry `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters`) exists. It did not. But if it would, make sure that the value is set to “1” and restart.
- Stopped the `OracleRemExecServiceV2` service

Comment: running the console as administrator fixed the issue for me ... thank u!